# How to pass Django filter args as arguments to other function

Tags: python, django

I want to make a class function that returns the result of a filter, but I want to be able to use it as if the function was a django filter too:

This is what I've tried:

```
def section_set_with_compound(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs
    return self.section_set.filter(Q(args) |Q(course__is_compound=True))
```

But im getting an error as if args and kwags are empty:

I want to be able to do:

```
myobject.section_set_with_compound(param1=1,param2__param3__=x,param4__icontains="ha..")
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use: `Q(**kwargs)`

Comment: But you do not use `kwargs` in your filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **use the asterisk and double asterisk (`*`) in the call to `Q`** as well:

```
def section_set_with_compound(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.section_set.filter(Q(*args, **kwargs) | Q(course__is_compound=True))
```

The `args` is a *tuple* with the *unnamed* parameters, `kwargs` is a dictionary with the *named* parameters. But in case you want to pass these again as unnamed and named parameters, you need to do a call with the asterisk as well.

Note that here you have constructed a **logical OR**, this means that the elements should *or* satisfy the filter with the arguments you work with, *or* the `course__is_compound` is `True` (or both at the same time).

In case you want a **logical AND**, you can use:

```
def section_set_with_compound(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.section_set.filter(*args, course__is_compound=True, **kwargs)
```

Now Django will filter rows such that all the conditions you enter hold, *and* the `course__is_compound` is set to `True`. This is **semantically different** compared to the first code fragment.